# Mysql Update errors on keys

Tags: mysql

```
Update AAA.master A, BBB.images B, BBB.content C 
set A.caption = B.image_txt where C.content_id_key = A.media_id
```

I get the following error although I am certain they are both primary keys. Do they have to have a PK->FK relationship? I dont think so.
  *You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the error.

But first of all you need to rewrite your query.
Repeat after me:

> I must not use implicit `where` joins, because they are confusing!

Rewrite the update query into this:

```
Update AAA.master a
INNER JOIN BBB.images b ON (a.someid = b.someid) #<<-- your error is here 
INNER JOIN BBB.content c ON (C.content_id_key = A.media_id)
SET A.caption = B.image_txt WHERE ........   #<<-- and also here
```

The first error you've made is that there's no join criterion between table A and B.
Second error is that **in strict mode** you need to have a `where` clause.
And you **did not** *I did* **no you did not** have a where clause, you just had a join criterion *disguised* as a where clause.

Also you're still a join criterion short and the real where clause short.

**This is why implicit joins suck so bad**

Answer (score 0):

it might be because you're not selecting a record from the table B in the WHERE part

Comment: No, I tried that.I even tried it with just the 2 tables. I read about turning off safe updates, but I'd rather not.Its almost like it doesnt see my where clause.